# Angular access to template file too much with DynamicComponentLoader

Tags: angular

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezhcab7W0nM2nvggbhxh?p=preview), I use the class DynamicComponentLoader to dynamically instantiate components :

```
this.dlc.loadIntoLocation(
      toComponent(template, directives, me.type), 
      this.elementRef,
      'anchor'
    );
```

However, when I open the Developer Tools Windows and look at the network tab, the html file associated to the component dynamically created is retrieved more than one time.
In the plunker, each template (from frame-test and frame-test2) is retrieved 3 times.

Why does the caching not working ?
Is it because the components are dynamically created so SystemJS doesn't know it have to not redownload the template ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!